# tinymce text area onclick event change check box value

Tags: editor, tinymce

i am using tinymce editor for my form.

i have three instance of tiny mce editor for three text area.

on click a particular textarea i want to select a check box option .

first time i am using tinymce editor .

how can i select check for onclick of textarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place this code into your plugins init-function. It adds an onclick handler:

```
// ed is the editor instance

ed.onNodeChange.add(function(ed){

   // here you need to run the code to activate your checkbox

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The TinyMCE object exposes an `onClick` member you can bind a function to as follows:

```
//ed as your tiny-mce variable
ed.onClick.add(function(){
    //Toggle checkbox here 
});
```